# Searching for equivalent of sfAction in Symfony 3 (one action per file)

Tags: symfony-3.3

Is there an alternative action syntax available to dispatch the actions in separate files - so one file per action. Reason: Better possibility for CVS collaboration (less merge conflicts). I found this one solution but I'm feeling not comfortable to extend a class called Action from a class called Controller. (I need the Controller class because of the rendering method below). To pass the controller as an argument is not working because it is not an injectable service. Is there a less ugly way? For example to define a rule within the services.yml to let the actions automatically inherit from "Controller" class?

Thx

```
 // ./src/AppBundle/Action/LayoutsAction.php

 <?php  

 namespace AppBundle\Action;

 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

 class LayoutsAction extends Controller {
     private $serializer;

     /**
     * The action is automatically registered as a service and dependencies are autowired.
     * Typehint any service you need, it will be automatically injected.
     */
     public function __construct(Serializer $serializer)
     {
         $this->serializer = $serializer;
     }

     /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
     public function __invoke(Request $request)
     {
         return $this->render('layout-editor/layouts.html.twig', [
             'initialState' => $this->serializer->normalize([
                 'layouts' => $this-get('layouts.repository.layout')-findAll()
             ])
         ]);
     }
 }
```

My services.yml is looking like this:

```
// ./app/config/services.yml

...

services:
     _defaults:
         autowire: true
         autoconfigure: true
         public: false

     AppBundle\:
         resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
         exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

     AppBundle\Action\:
         resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Action'
         public: true

     AppBundle\Controller\:
         resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
         public: true
         tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
...
```